# What is the correct definition of the root mean square percentage error (RMSPE)?

Tags: error, rms

[Göçken et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417415006570?via%3Dihub) define the root mean square percentage error (RMSPE) as
\begin{equation}
\text{RMSPE} = \sqrt{\frac{100\%}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta X^2_{\text{rel},i}}
\end{equation}
with 
\begin{equation}
 \Delta X_{\text{rel},i}=\frac{X_i}{T_i}-1,
\end{equation}
where $T_i$ is the desired value and $X_i$ is the actual value.

However, [Göçken et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417415006570?via%3Dihub) and [Webber et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378429015300678?via%3Dihub) define the root mean square relative error (RMSRE) as:

\begin{equation}
\text{RMSRE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta X^2_{\text{rel},i}}
\end{equation}

If we express the actual error $\Delta X_{\text{rel},i}$ as a percentage and name it $\Delta X_{\%,i}$, then we have:
\begin{equation}
 \Delta X_{\%,i}=\left(\frac{X_i}{T_i}-1\right)\cdot 100\%=\Delta X_{\text{rel},i} \cdot 100\%
\end{equation}

From my understanding, RMSPE should be the same as RMSRE, where $\Delta X_{\text{rel},i}$ is substituted by $\Delta X_{\text{%},i}$. However, this would yield
\begin{equation}
\text{RMSPE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta X^2_{\text{rel},i}} \cdot 100\%,
\end{equation}
which differs from the original definition of Göçken et al. by a factor of 10. Are my considerations correct and if so, are there alternative sources for the RMSPE?

Comment: $\sqrt{100\%}=100\%=1$. There is no factor of $10$ difference, though putting it inside the square root is misleading.

Comment: That... makes sense. And it just took 3 years for someone to point it out. :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several alternative sources ([Swanson et al.](https://cssd.ucr.edu/Papers/PDFs/MAPE-R%20EMPIRICAL%20V24%20Swanson%20Tayman%20Bryan.pdf), [Fomby](http://faculty.smu.edu/tfomby/eco5385_eco6380/lecture/Scoring%20Measures%20for%20Prediction%20Problems.pdf), [Shcherbakov et al.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/435e/b6e05fcda264c8c1e7fbcdee7116bb5b1424.pdf)), which agree that the RMSPE is defined as:
\begin{equation}
\text{RMSPE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta X^2_{\text{rel},i}} \cdot 100\%
\end{equation}